# Create text Stroke for UILabel iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I was wondering how can I create text stroke for UILabel in iOS4 ? I need some suggestion . I want something like this :

[image]

EDITED :

```
UIFont *font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:222];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0,0);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.7);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 2, 2, 2, 1.0);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// I change it to my outlet
[label.text drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Well, if you want to draw a text in a label with a custom font, like CGFontRef, it is not quite simple. I have googled a little and found a solution for you which implies you to inherit UILabel class and rewrite drawTextInRect method for this. All the necessary information for you is [here](http://blog.mro.name/2010/08/uilabel-with-a-custom-cgfont/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
UIFont *font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0,0);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.7);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[@"Label" drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

you can look here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html

and in the example code here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531

Comment: thank you but nothing changed ! ... is  @"Label" my outlet ? sorry Iam novice in IOS programming, I put my code on viewDidLoad

Comment: @"Lable" is just a String, the text you  want to print

Comment: @Mc.Lover: This is not correct ans means why you are accepted this ans??

Comment: This works great. However, the `CGContextSaveCGState(context);` line is in the wrong place. It should come before the `CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.7);`. Otherwise all other text will also have a stroke applied, as the state that is restored is the one including the stroke and fill color.

Answer (score 2):

I have a clean solution implementing UILabelStroke subclass:

```
@implementation UILabelStroked
@synthesize strokeColor;
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIColor *borderColor = self.strokeColor;
    UIColor *fillColor = self.textColor;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = borderColor;
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.0f);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
    self.textColor = fillColor;
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
@end
```